# NextJS: Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Using this code I am trying to load Markdown files that are stored in the /legal directory. As loading these files needs to be run on the server, I am using `getStaticProps`. According to my knowledge and what I could find on the internet, this is the place where I can use `fs`. The problem is that when I access the page, I get this error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
```

Does anyone have a solution to this. Is there anything wrong with the imports or the server-side code?

```
import marked from 'marked';
import getConfig from 'next/config';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const { serverRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()

    function getLegalDocument(key: string, locale: string) { 
        return marked.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(serverRuntimeConfig.PROJECT_ROOT, './legal', key + '.' + locale + '.md'), 'utf8'))
    }

    let legalDocuments = { 
        legalNotice: {
            de: getLegalDocument('legal_notice', 'de'),
            en: getLegalDocument('legal_notice', 'en'),
            es: getLegalDocument('legal_notice', 'es'),
            fr: getLegalDocument('legal_notice', 'fr'),
            it: getLegalDocument('legal_notice', 'it'),
        },
        privacyPolicy: {
            de: getLegalDocument('privacy_policy', 'de'),
            en: getLegalDocument('privacy_policy', 'en'),
            es: getLegalDocument('privacy_policy', 'es'),
            fr: getLegalDocument('privacy_policy', 'fr'),
            it: getLegalDocument('privacy_policy', 'it'),
        },
        termsOfService: {
            de: getLegalDocument('terms_of_service', 'de'),
            en: getLegalDocument('terms_of_service', 'en'),
            es: getLegalDocument('terms_of_service', 'es'),
            fr: getLegalDocument('terms_of_service', 'fr'),
            it: getLegalDocument('terms_of_service', 'it'),
        }
    }

    return { 
        props: legalDocuments,
    }
};

type Props = {
    legalDocuments?: any;
    documentType: string;
}

const LegalDocument = ({ legalDocuments, documentType }: Props) => {
    const languages: Map<String, String> = legalDocuments[documentType]
    const { locale, locales, defaultLocale, asPath } = useRouter();
    let document = ''
    
    if (locale in languages) {
        document = languages[locale]
    } else if (defaultLocale in languages) {
        document = languages[defaultLocale]
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                {documentType}
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            {document}
        </div>
    )
}

export default LegalDocument
```

Comment: That code should definitely not throw that error as you're correctly only using `fs` and `path` on the server. Have you tried deleting your `.next` folder are re-starting your dev server? It could be a caching issue with Next.js.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
    if (!isServer) {
      config.node = {
        fs: 'empty'
      }
    }

    return config
  }
}
```

Comment: So do I need to setup webpack? I am not using it yet in this project as far as I know.

Comment: With what you have provided I get the following output: `ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema` followed by: `configuration[0].node has an unknown property 'fs'`

Comment: This is my current `next.config.js`: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/ibanujoliv.typescript